# 'onclick' button not giving address using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) to make a voting macro. I've got everything working fine, except for a button click.

Code for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Vote: Runelocus" onclick="window.open('http://www.runelocus.com/toplist/index.php?action=vote&amp;id=277&amp;id2=333119125058'); setStatus(1);">
```

Every time I click this button, instead of the getting the link, I get a `system._comobject`.

This is the code I'm using to get the address

```
Try
    Dim ele As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement

    Dim target As String = ele.GetAttribute("onclick")
    target = target.Replace("'); setStatus(1);", String.Empty)
    target = target.Replace("window.open('", String.Empty)

    e.Cancel = True
    Dim window As New Voter()
    window.Show()
    window.WebBrowser1.Navigate(target)

    status.Items.Add(target)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim target As String = ele.DomElement.attributes("onclick").value.ToString
```